# How to use a shell variable inside sed when doing "d" command?

Tags: bash, variables, sed, line

In my bash, I wish to delete lines from 1 to ${number}, like this:

```
number=10
sed '1,${number}d' myfile
```

It failed with syntax error.
I also tried "\${number}", '"$number"', neithers works

---

I changed to double quote, it works under command line, but not inside bash script file. How to make it work?

Comment: You need to put your variable outside of the quoted sed statement and so: sed '1,'${number}'d' myfile

Comment: Show the *exact* error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I changed to double quote, it works under command line, but not inside
>   bash script file

Assuming your bash script is:

```
sed "1,${number}d" myfile
```

you should export `number` variable in bash prompt so that it can be visible in bash script when it is run:

```
export number=10
```

Answer (score 2):

Enclose your *sed* expression in double quotes to interpolate the variable `number`:

```
sed "1,${number}d" file
```

Comment: Thanks, it works under command line, but doesn't work inside a bash script. Seems bash script will do '1,$d' which will delete all.

Comment: `number` isn't defined in the script.

Comment: @HindForsum, post the crucial fragment of your bash script to your question so I could see  your "sed" usage

Answer (score 2):

Please use double quotes instead of single quotes while running sed this way. 
Read here for [Difference between single and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)